# Postgresql can't see tables of other users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a PostgreSQL server on my laptop. I configured Postgres, so that it accepts remote access from my other computer.

Whenever I connect to the database from first machine and make a table in the database I can't see these changes on the second machine. Even when I connect with the user of the first machine (postgres user), I still can't see them. Neither does the first machine sees the tables that were created on the second machine. (I don't use transactions).

For example, I made a table named Users in the first machine, but I can't see them on the second. I've made a table named Pet on the second machine, but I can't see them on the first one.

Comment: Have you made sure that on each machine you are definitely connecting to the other machine to check these things and not inadvertently to the same machine?

Comment: I don't use transactions.

Comment: @Jon I think you might be right.I'll check it.

Comment: [SOLVED] @JonClements , you were right.I was trying to connect to the database with my public ip(192....),instead i should've just used the external ip.